# How to make points representing a 2D line denser in Python

Tags: python, numpy

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

**Problem**

I have  a 2 arrays, representing datapoints on a line. For example:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2])
y = np.array([5,6,4])
```

Plot the data:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y,c='r')
```

Get:

[image]

I'd like to have arrays where the datapoints represent the same lines as above, but they are doubled. The desired result is:

```
new_x = np.array([0,0.5,1,1.5,2]) # this is the result I am looking for
new_y = np.array([5,5.5,6,5,4]) # this is the result I am looking for
```

Plot:

```
plt.plot(new_x,new_y)
plt.scatter(new_x,new_y,c='r')
```

Result:

[image]

---

**My attempt**

My method of doing this:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2])
y = np.array([5,6,4])

new_x=[]
for index, each in enumerate(x):
    if index!=0:
        new_x.append((each+x[index-1])/2)

new_y=[]
for index, each in enumerate(y):
    if index!=0:
        new_y.append((each+y[index-1])/2)

new_x.extend(x)
new_y.extend(y)
```

Plot:

```
plt.plot(new_x,new_y)
plt.scatter(new_x,new_y,c='r')
```

Result:

[image]

Points are in the right place, the new points added are the correct points, but they are put into the `new_x` & `new_y` arrays in the wrong order. It is fixable by paying more attention to the `.extend`, but this does not seem a good method to me anyway, because of the iteration.

---

**My research**

- [linear interpolation between two data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282659/linear-interpolation-between-two-data-points): doesn't use 2D arrays
- [How to write a function that returns an interpolated value (pandas dataframe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294496/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-an-interpolated-value-pandas-dataframe): deals with interpolated values of functions, not resampling lines as above

And there are some other questions with the `[interpolation]` tag, but I haven't found one descibing this problem above.

---

**Question**

**How do I get the above described `new_x` and `new_y`, preferably without iteration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these one-liner list comprehensions:

```
new_x = [j for i, v in enumerate(x) for j in [v, (x[i] + x[(i + 1 if (len(x) - 1) != i else i)]) / 2]]
new_y = [j for i, v in enumerate(y) for j in [v, (y[i] + y[(i + 1 if (len(y) - 1) != i else i)]) / 2]]
plt.plot(new_x, new_y)
plt.scatter(new_x, new_y, c='r')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Babou]